# What is the use of swap() function in priority_queue class in C++?

Tags: c++11, data-structures, stl, priority-queue, swap

I was exploring priority_queue class in C++ and couldn't think about any practical use of swap().

Ref: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/swap/

Can someone list a practical example where it is beneficial to use this function. Essentially it feels like renaming the priority queue variable.

```
std::priority_queue<int> foo,bar;
foo.push (15); foo.push(30); foo.push(10);
bar.push (101); bar.push(202);

foo.swap(bar);

std::cout << "size of foo: " << foo.size() << '\n';
std::cout << "size of bar: " << bar.size() << '\n';
```

Comment: Likely of mostly historical significance. `swap` was the poor-man's `move` pre-C++11. All containers have it, it's not unique to `priority_queue`. Back then, you would "move" an element into a vector like this: `std::vector<std::priority_queue<int> > v; v.push_back(std::priority_queue<int>()); v.back().swap(myQueue);`

Comment: 'Copy and swap' is a well known idiom for implementing copy assignment. For this reason (and others) it's useful to be able to efficiently swap objects.

Comment: If you had a class, where it contained a priority queue as a member, your class could be a vector element, you might have a swap member function for your class (to be used by std::sort). That swap member function might call the priority queues swap in implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swap` is a library-wide feature; many of the classes in the standard library support swap. It's also a customization point; you can specialize `std::swap` for your own classes.

As to what it's useful for - there's lots of algorithms that use it (all the sorting algorithms, for example) and some of the containers use it internally.

A `swap` that is `noexcept` is a great tool for writing exception-safe code.